# Something to replace e.datatransfer.files?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I have my drop function

```
    function drop(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    var files = e.dataTransfer.files;
    validateImage(files);
    }
```

but files is returned null in firefox. In Chrome everything is ok, in files I have stored the image dropped, but firefox is returning null.

Comment: can you send the code for dataTransfer object?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x7tufLrp/3/  -- better I put the fiddle with the whole application

Comment: what about `e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files`?

Comment: can't read dataTransfer of undefined

Comment: @WarrenG try this ` $(dropbox).on("drop", drop);` and in drop function `console.log(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer);` does this work?